# How to check if particular characters appeared in same order?

Tags: c, string, parsing

For example I have a string: `PO-ELK=SAEER:SWE`

`-` must always be before `=` and that should always be before `:`.

Is there a easy way I could check to see if those conditions are met in the string I input and if not an error is returned.

Comment: `-,=,:` each character is there is only one?

Comment: If a string has multiple occurrences of the delimiters `-`, `=` or `:`, the post is not clear on the desired functionality.  If functionality with multiple delimiters is important, please provide detail.

Answer (score 2):

Just a little programming needed.

```
const char *symbol = "-=:";
const char *s = "PO-ELK=SAEER:SWE";
while (*s) {
  if (*s == *symbol) symbol++;
  s++;
}
if (*symbol) puts("Fail");
else puts("Success");
```

Comment: Very pretty and upvoted. Still, I think I'd write `if (((p = strchr(s, '-'))) && ((p = strchr(p, '='))) && strchr(p, ':'))`

Comment: @rici Agree about `strchr()` - thought that [too](http://stackoverflow.com/a/35003145/2410359)

Answer (score 1):

Sort-of interesting problem, it might be good for <kbd>code-golf</kbd>

```
$ cat > yesno.c
#include <stdio.h>
#include <strings.h>

int main(int ac, char **av) {
  char *s = "-=:",
      *s0 = s,
       *i = av[1];

  while(*s && i && *i) {
    if(index(s0, *i)) {
      if(*i == *s) {
        ++i;
        ++s;
        continue;
      } else
        break;
    }
    ++i;
  }
  printf("%s\n", *s ? "no" : "yes");
}

^D
$ cc -Wall yesno.c
$ ./a.out PO-ELK=SAEER:SWE
```

There are some grey areas in the spec tho. Are the characters ever duplicated? And if so do we search for a subsequence that *is* in-order? Do we require that all three are found? Does the program need to be interactive or can it just use the shell args?

Answer (score 1):

How about 3 calls to `strchr()`?

```
const char *s = "PO-ELK=SAEER:SWE";
const char *t;
if ((t = strchr(s, '-')) && (t = strchr(t, '=')) && (t = strchr(t, ':'))) puts("Success");
else puts("Failure");
```

Comment: It is a wrong approach because condition (t = strchr(s, '-')) does not guarantee that there was not for example '=' before '-'.

Comment: @Vlad from Moscow Maybe:  OP's wording can be taken various ways and unfortunately [this hour old comment](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/35002316/how-to-check-if-particular-characters-appeared-in-same-order/35003145?noredirect=1#comment57733085_35002316) has not resulted in additional info.  ":PO-ELK=SAEER:SWE" may be valid as "- must always be before = and that should always be before **a** :"  OTOH it fails with "- must always be before = and that should always be before **all** :".  It is a subtly of English not conveyed clearly enough yet by OP.

Answer (score 0):

Use `std::string::find`. Make use of second argument.

First look for "-" and if it could be find, search for "=" passing position of "-" as start point. Then do the same for ":" with position of "=" as a second argument.

Comment: This is a C question.

Comment: oh :) I saw 'string' in the question and I've switched to c++ ;)

Answer (score 0):

You can use the `strchr` function, which return a pointer to the character in the string.  So you can call this function for each of the characters in question and check that the indexes are in the right order.

```
const char *str = "PO-ELK=SAEER:SWE";
const char *dashPtr = strchr(str,'-');
const char *equalPtr = strchr(str,'=');
const char *colonPtr = strchr(str,':');

if ((dashIdx  == NULL) || (equalIdx == NULL) || (colonIdx == NULL)) {
    printf("one of -, =, : not found\n");
} else {
    if ((dashPtr < equalPtr) && (equalPtr < colonPtr)) {
        printf("order correct\n");
    } else {
        printf("order incorrect\n");
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Use state machine in this kind of problem :
Here is my solution, i didn't test it but it should give you some ideas

```
#include <string.h>
#include <stdio.h>
typedef enum {init, s1,s2,s3,end}eState;
int main()
{
 char str[20] ="PO-ELK=SAEER:SWE";
 int iExit = 0;
 int i =0;
 char c;
 eState state = init;

 while (!iExit)
 {
  c=str[i];
  switch (state)
  {
      case init:
        if (c =='-')
            state = s1;
        else if ((c =='=')||(c ==':'))
            state = end;
        break;
      case s1:
        if (c =='=')
            state = s2;
        else if(c ==':'||c=='-')
            state = end;
        break;
      case s2:
        if (c ==':')
            state = s3;
        else if(c =='='||c=='-')
            state = end;
        break;
      case s3:
        printf ("Succes \n");
        iExit = 1;
        break;
      case end:
        printf ("Error \n"),
        iExit = 1;
        break;
      default :
        break;
   }

  i++;
}

return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use the idea shown in this demonstrative program. The advantage of this approach is that you can write just an if-statement to check a string.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

int main( void )
{    
    const char *s = "PO-ELK=SAEER:SWE";
    const char *t = "-=:";
    size_t n = 0;

    if ( s[n = strcspn( s + n, t )] == t[0] &&
         s[n += 1 + strcspn( s + n + 1, t )] == t[1] &&
         s[n += 1 + strcspn( s + n + 1, t )] == t[2] )
    {
        printf( "\"%s\" is a valid string\n", s );
    }
    else
    {
        printf( "\"%s\" is not a valid string\n", s );
    }

    s = "PO-ELK:SAEER=SWE";
    n = 0;

    if ( s[n = strcspn( s + n, t )] == t[0] &&
         s[n += 1 + strcspn( s + n + 1, t )] == t[1] &&
         s[n += 1 + strcspn( s + n + 1, t )] == t[2] )
    {
        printf( "\"%s\" is a valid string\n", s );
    }
    else
    {
        printf( "\"%s\" is not a valid string\n", s );
    }

    return 0;
}
```

The program output

```
"PO-ELK=SAEER:SWE" is a valid string
"PO-ELK:SAEER=SWE" is not a valid string
```

To guarantee that the string does not contain more than one of each target character you can write the condition the following way

```
if ( s[n = strcspn( s + n, t )] == t[0] &&
     s[n += 1 + strcspn( s + n + 1, t )] == t[1] &&
     s[n += 1 + strcspn( s + n + 1, t )] == t[2] &&
     s[n += 1 + strcspn( s + n + 1, t )] == '\0' )
```